# Taking code written for a native iOS app and turning it into a DLL

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've gotten the [Bluetooth LE data transfer sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) up and running on my ipad. However what I really want to do is to take this example and make it work within Unity.

I know Unity supports the creation and importing of custom DLL files and I'm wondering the following:

1. is it possible to take code written for a native iOS device and library (in this case the core bluetooth) and turn that into a DLL?
2. how would I go about turning this into a DLL?

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop a Unity plugin. There isn't too many resources for this topic: but I found this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/unity-native-plugins-os-x/ It goes step-by-step through the process and explains everything clearly.

The simplest solution for you is to implement a wrapper around the CBCentralManager APIs. Implement some initialization API and make sure the plugin sets a delegate. The callbacks on the delegate will have to be forwarded as callbacks to the C# code. Similarly implement the peripheral APIs. To further simplify the interaction APIs, using basic types for arguments (primitive types, strings) instead of objects is probably a good idea.